# upload a file with Karate testing through web interface using a Selenium grid and jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, testing, karate

I'm experiencing some problems using karate testing when uploading a file through a web interface using a Selenium grid cluster (Zalenium) and Jenkins:

1. find an easy way for getting the full path of the file to be able to send it to the input web element with:

   `waitFor(inputFieldSelector).input(fullPathOfThefile)`

   I solved this using a custom java method to reconstruct it but for sure there's a faster/more elegant way. Is there a specific Karate function/way for get it?
2. find a way to set up the remote webdriver to handle the local files as it seems that it searches the file to upload in the wrong place.

   In Java I solved it using setFileDetector of RemoteWebDriver with LocalFileDetector (an example is shown below) but I don't know how to do it in Karate:

   ```
   RemoteWebDriver rwd = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(gridUrl), DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
   rwd.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may need investigation, to be honest we haven't worked on file-uploads to that extent, so we may need your help. For point 1, a custom Java method sounds good to me but you can suggest a new API and we can add it to Karate in the next version, maybe `karate.toAbsolutePath('classpath:some/file.txt')`

Any reference you can point us to for the `FileDetector` will help - it would be great if you can contribute code. At the very least, please consider submitting a sample in this form: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test

Comment: I'll try to make some example in ui-test. I think that anyway, even if the usage of absolute path is discouraged, that method could be useful in particular situation like the one I mentioned.